# NSData access bytes cause memory leak

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, nsdata

I use NSData object to maintain memory data. But when I use NSData.bytes to access the memory data. It will cause memory leak.
The sample code is as following:

```
char buf[12];

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData  *tempData;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tempData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buf length:12];

    [self loopReadData];
}

- (void)loopReadData {
    while(true) {
        [self calcData:self.tempData];
    }
}

- (void)calcData:(NSData *) data {
    const void *dataPtr = data.bytes;       ///< memory leak
    sleep(0.1);
}

@end
```

The sample code is very simple.But will cause memory leak and crash my app when no memory exits.

Answer (score 2):

If I add autoreleasepool to the code. There is no memory leak again.

```
- (void)loopReadData {
    while(true) {
        @autoreleasepool {
           [self calcData:self.tempData];
        }
    }
}
```